# Text in the GWT Designer appears as <Dynamic> when Internationalizing my application

Tags: gwt, internationalization

Following the offical GWT example: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n

if I do something like:
btnPManager.setText(constants.pManagerButton());

Then in the GWT Designer the button appears with the text `<Dynamic>`.

As I go through my appliction and add more things, soon all the text will say `<Dynamic>`.  This is just in the designer, when I run my app everything is fine.

Is there a way to get the real text in the designer and not have this `<Dynamic>` stuff?  It will get very confusing if I do not find a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has "gone away".  I say that because I do not know what the original cause was, but now in the designer the `<dynamic>` has been replaced by actual text.  Since I wrote this, eclipse crashed (it ran out of memory).  I have since upped the memory it can use.

This may have NOTHING to do with why the designer now puts in the actual text or it might be the reason.  In any case, I can internationalize and see the text in the designer.

If anyone else has this problem try restarting eclipse, and if that doesn't work, boost the memory (I went to a min of 1gig from 40meg and a max of 2 gigs from 512meg).